# second derivative inequality

Tags: derivatives, inequality, smooth-functions

I was reading a paper and the autor did the following inequality, but I couldn't understand why:

If $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth and bounded then
$$|u(x+y)-u(x)-\nabla u(x)\cdot y|\leq C||D^2u||_{\infty}|y|^2$$

PS:
Using the Mean Value Inequality, I could only get that
$$|u(x+y)-u(x)-\nabla u(x)\cdot y|\leq C||Du||_{\infty}|y|$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Taylor formula with integral error term.